# how to define a literal type based on a value inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, flowtype

In flow, I can define a dynamic literal type like this:

```
const myVar = 'foo'

type X = {
  [typeof myVar]: string
}

const myX: X = { foo: 1 } // will throw, because number
const myX: X = { foo: 'bar' } // will not throw
```

I'm trying to convert some code now to typescript, where this syntax is not possible. However, I can't figure out how to do it in typescript. Here is the code that I'm working with (partial translated to typescript already):

```js
type Theme = {
  fontSizes: number[]
}

type SystemObj = {
  prop: string,
  cssProperty?: string,
}

type Props<T> = T & {
  theme: Theme,
}

const style = <X>({
  prop,
  cssProperty,
}: SystemObj) => {
  const cssProp = cssProperty || prop

  return (props: Props<{
    [typeof cssProp]: X
  }>) => {
    return props
  }
}

const fontSize = style<number>({
  prop: 'fontSize',
})

fontSize({
  fontSize: 2,
  theme: {
    fontSizes: [12, 14, 16],
  }
})
```

Currently throws (with all options turned on on the typescript playground)

```
Argument of type '{ fontSize: number; theme: { fontSizes: number[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ theme: Theme; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fontSize' does not exist in type '{ theme: Theme; }'.
```

**EDIT:**

So I got it to work, exactly how I want it to work:

```
type Theme = {
  fontSizes: number[]
}

type SystemObj = {
  prop: string,
  cssProperty?: string,
}

type Props = {
  theme: Theme,
}

const style = <X extends string, Y>({
  prop,
  cssProperty,
}: SystemObj) => {
  const cssProp = cssProperty || prop

  return (props: Props & { [K in X]: Y }) => {
    return props
  }
}

const fontSize = style<'fontSize', number>({
  prop: 'fontSize',
})

fontSize({
  fontSize: 123,
  theme: {
    fontSizes: [12, 14, 16],
  }
})
```

Is it possible to get rid of the `<'fontSize'` part here though?:

```
const fontSize = style<'fontSize', number>({
  prop: 'fontSize',
})
```

and just type this as

```
const fontSize = style<number>({
  prop: 'fontSize',
})
```

it's working exactly how I want it to work, just wondering if I can remove the duplication here (because the `prop: 'fontSize'` defines the key already). Which leads back to my original question, how I can define the value `fontSize` here as the key inside my type.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is. You can use the same approach in TypeScript too. The only thing you have to change is to replace `[typeof myVar]` with `[myVar]`. I don't know Flow that well but I doubt that you actually have to use `[typeof myVar]` to get the *content* of `myVar` as `typeof myVar` will evaluate to "string", not "foo".

Comment: well that's the thing, I do want the _content_ of the string to be the key here.
so that this part:
`
return (props: Props<{
    [typeof cssProp]: X
  }>) => {
    return props
  }
`
returns has the type of  `{ theme: Theme, fontSize: number }`

Comment: I got it working exactly how I want it to be now @str, see my edit above
however, I wonder if I can remove the `const style = <'fontSize'` part, as the object I pass into the function defines the key already.

Comment: @MartinBroder I don't think this is possible atm because TS doesn't allow the partial explicit definition of generic types: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571 But you could at least ensure the property value and the generic literal are equivalent:
type SystemObj<X> = {
  prop: X,
  cssProperty?: string,
}

const style = <X extends string, Y>({
  prop,
  cssProperty,
}: SystemObj<X>) => {
  const cssProp = cssProperty || prop

  return (props: Props & { [K in X]: Y }) => {
    return props
  }
}

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's the purpose of the `SystemObj` and show real use case? 
You could achieve the same effect (like in edited example) by just: `const style = <T>() => (props: Props & T) => props;
const fontSize = style<{fontSize: number}>();`

Comment: the SystemObj defines some more properties that I'm going to use inside the style function. I don't think you need the details as they are unrelated to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment because you want to partially specify and partially infer type arguments. Once [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) lands in TypeScript you will be able to do something like this:

```
type SystemObj<T extends string> = { // <------ note T here
  prop: T,
  cssProperty?: string,
}

type Props = {
  theme: Theme,
}

const style = <X extends string, Y>({
  prop,
  cssProperty,
}: SystemObj<X>) => { // <---------------------- X as an argument here
  const cssProp = cssProperty || prop

  return (props: Props & { [K in X]: Y }) => {
    return props
  }
}

const fontSize = style<_, number>({ // <-------- Ask TS to infer type param
  prop: 'fontSize',
})

fontSize({
  fontSize: 123,
  theme: {
    fontSizes: [12, 14, 16],
  }
})
```

Comment: Ugh, okay. Hurts my feelings that I can not correctly type this right now. Or lets say, not in an easy way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without partial argument type inference, you could split `style` function into "two parts" - `style` will return a function accepting `SystemObj`. This way you'll be able to specify value type (`number`) and prop name will be inferred from `SystemObj`:

```
type SystemObj<TProp extends string> = {
    prop: TProp,
    cssProperty?: string,
}

const style = <TValue>() =>
    <TKey extends string>(systemObj: SystemObj<TKey>) =>
        (props: Props & { [K in TKey]: TValue }) => props

const fontSize = style<number>()({
    prop: 'fontSize',
})

fontSize({
    fontSize: 123,
    theme: {
        fontSizes: [12, 14, 16],
    }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Theme%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fontSizes%3A%20number%5B%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20Props%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20theme%3A%20Theme%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20SystemObj%3CTProp%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20TProp%2C%0A%20%20%20%20cssProperty%3F%3A%20string%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20style%20%3D%20%3CTValue%3E()%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTKey%20extends%20string%3E(systemObj%3A%20SystemObj%3CTKey%3E)%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(props%3A%20Props%20%26%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20TKey%5D%3A%20TValue%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20props%0A%0Aconst%20fontSize%20%3D%20style%3Cnumber%3E()(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20'fontSize'%2C%0A%7D)%0A%0AfontSize(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fontSize%3A%20123%2C%0A%20%20%20%20theme%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontSizes%3A%20%5B12%2C%2014%2C%2016%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))